# How to iterate through all html elements of the same type but apply different changes to each one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code contains div tags nested within a single div tag. Each of these nested  tags has two attributes, one is "number" and the other is "type". At one point in my code, I need to go over all of these div elements, select only those which have type="guessed" and change their text to the value of their respective "number" attribute.

More specifically:

```
$('div div[type="guessed"]').text(???);
```

I can't figure out what to type in place of the question marks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the anonymous function available to `text()`:

```
$('div div[type="guessed"]').text(function(){
    return this.getAttribute('number');
    /* Or, to use more jQuery:
    return $(this).attr('number');
    */
});
```

Note, though, that neither `type` nor `number` are valid attributes of the `<div>` element.

As noted in the comments if you wish to add custom attributes to an element it's better – under HTML 5 – to use the `data-*` attributes, which will validate under the HTML 5 doctype (`<!doctype html>`). Using non-prefixed attributes will work, but they are, however, invalid (under both HTML 4.x and 5).

References:

- [`data-*` custom attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, I'm using custom attributes. Are you implying this is bad practice in general?

Comment: [Data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) would be a better choice, @NPex.

Comment: @NPex - no it's OK in my opinion, but try to put a structure before (e.g. `my-app-name-number="123"`) - in case other things implement an identical name

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps

```
$('div div[type="guessed"]').text($(this).attr('number'));
```

Comment: `$(this)` won't reference the current element. So this answer doesn't work. -1

Comment: Please consider adding at least some words explaining to the OP and to further readers of you answer why and how it does reply to the original question.